# Will my voice sit better in the mix with a baritone guitar?

Tags: guitar, voice, vocal-range, transposition, instrument-range

I have a deep singing voice (pleasant range: E2 to D4, extreme range: B flat 1 to F4). It is not shockingly bassy but warm. So if I want to cover a song, I need to transpose it. But I have to transpose every song to such a degree that it is impractical with a capo and when I simply transpose the chords my voice blends too much with the guitar resulting in a muddy sound and the ornamentation of the original track is lost. The frequencies of the guitar and my voice overlap too much. I think that a baritone guitar could solve my problem as then I would shift the frequency spectrum of the guitar down as much as the frequency spectrum of my voice is shifted down in comparison to many pop singers. Could this, in theory, result in a nicer, clearer sound? I have seen that others have asked a similar question but I believe that no one has addressed the issue regarding how the voice "sits" with the guitar.

Comment: I'd have thought that the opposite would happen - the lower sound of a baritone guitar will be closer to your voice range. Have you tried all other voicing options with a standard guitar - at least all five chord shapes in common usage, with or without capo?

Comment: No, the idea is to take a pop song and shift the vocals and the guitar down a fourth. Then the vocals would be the same relative to the guitar as the original.

I haven't experimented with all possible voicings. Perhaps, I'm being lazy, but I think my idea could also result in a cool sound. I'll do an extensive experiment this weekend.

Comment: Sounds like it's worth trying. I've been meaning to try baritone strings for a while now but keep forgetting.

Comment: It may work, although the low tuning on baritone may make chords sound too muddy. Try, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Tim was right. The chords sounded too muddy with a baritone guitar.